# Browser Link Target Hint Without <a/> Tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, hyperlink

In most browsers, it's very familiar to see the target of a link (that is, an actual `<a>` tag) in an area of the browser's choosing when hovering over it (in Chrome, the bottom left grey popup).

Is there any notation one can use to tell the browser to mimic this on a tag that *isn't* an `<a>`? I'm kind of guessing not since I suppose there would be security considerations to allowing developers to tell the user they were hovering over a link to target `X` when really intending to do `Y`, but was wondering so thought I'd ask.

Comment: Since other elements don't have a target, what would you want a browser to put there?

Comment: You could just make a fake one with the same colors and simply `position fixed; bottom:0px; left: 0px;` then color is something like `background-color: grey` and then bind a `show` function on hovering the "pseudo <a> tags"
there is no officiall way to do it

Comment: you can simply use an `<A class=noclick href="#not a url but more of an instruction">` tag, and you can stop all .noclick tags from doing anything with JS.

Comment: @HoboSapiens really it was because in modern web apps (especially SPAs) people often actually navigate around with interactive divs etc, and I wondered if there was a way to say "this is where you'll be navigated to" without actually having to use A tags with all their limitations (not nestable, for one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be, but not in any modern browser that I know of.  This takes me back to the IE 4 days.

```
window.status = 'Your status bar text here';
```